# Can we defined limited access to unmanaged devices and also to certain users who use managed devices

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, accesscontrol

Inside SharePoint online we can define limited access on unmanaged devices:

[image]

but in our case we need to define limited access to certain users even if they access the sites from managed devices, is this possible?

Second question, can we control this on per site basis also?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a couple of ideas from the below article.

[Control access from unmanaged devices](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/control-access-from-unmanaged-devices)

Basically, what happens is that Conditional Access can control access to the SharePoint Service and Site Collections, in general.

There's an [article](https://alberthoitingh.com/2017/10/10/conditional-access-for-site-collections-in-sharepoint-online/), that defines how you can set Conditional Access on Site Collection Level (I haven't tried it out yet)

In order to achieve what you are looking for, you will have to use a mixture of security policies involving SharePoint Groups and Azure Active Directory Conditional Access policies.